# OOP Design - Performance vs Loose coupling

Tags: php, performance

I'm looking to improve my OOP code design as far as I can, but I'm stuck on this issue.

For example, I want to get the profiles of all friends of a user, in a social networking site. So I have tables `Friendships` and `Profiles`. And I have classes `Friends` and `Profile`.

Let `Friends` be the class that handle a user's friendships and `Friends::getFriendsProfiles()` be the function that fetches and returns all the user's friends' profiles.

So inside my function `Friends::getFriendsProfiles()` I can either do a

1. A table join 
   (e.g. `SELECT * FROM Friends LEFT JOIN Profiles ON Friends.user2 = Profile.userId WHERE Friends.user1 = :userid`), or
2. I can just fetch the user ids of the friends, create a `Profile` object for each friend id, and call `$profile->getProfile($friendid)` which runs a query (`SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE userId = $friendid`) to fetch a friend's profile. Then return the set of all the friends' `Profile` object.

**Option 1 Disadvantage:** My Friendship class knows about Profiles. And when I need to make a change on the way a profile is returned (e.g. I want to add another property to each profile object), I need to change it in 2 different places.

**Option 2 Disadvantages:** Instead of making 1 query (which I think should run in O(1) ?), it is now O(n) where n is the number of the user's friends.

But Option 2 is so much cleaner and loosely coupled. Which option should I take?

Comment: You're not writing a framework or a library of independent services. You're writing an application which models a tightly coupled real world situation. How more tightly coupled then friendship does real world come?

Comment: This question is about SQL and completely unrelated to OOP or application design.

Comment: Two tips from my point of view: *1)* I'd guess you created the DB tables first and then built the model, didn't you? While this approach is valid, it leads often to a model, where the responsibilities are not clear, like in your case. Maybe you should try to create the model first. Then I hardly see a `Friends` class, because what is a friend? I'd believe a friend is nothing else than another `User`, so `friends` is an (maybe *n:m*) association and no class. *2)* You should evaluate the usage of an ORM (object relational mapper), so that you don't have to worry about the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1 Disadvantage: My Friendship class knows about Profiles. And
>   when I need to make a change on the way a profile is returned (e.g. I
>   want to add another property to each profile object), I need to change
>   it in 2 different places.

Domain objects are naturally going to have some coupling. This is just the reality of the system you are modelling. This is not so much a coupling problem between friendship and profile its a problem of tight coupling between your business layer and your data layer. If you had a datamapper, finder class etc and made your business object persitance ignorant then changes like this should not matter too much.

If you use the second option you run into the [n+1 select problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97197/1914530). In this instance I would not sacrifice performance when there are more important areas that you could consider decoupling.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with Option 1 and only use 1 query.
The `Friends` class must not know much about the `Profiles` if the constructor could work with an array.
You could do something like:

```
SELECT Profiles.*
FROM Friends
LEFT JOIN Profiles ON Friends.user2 = Profile.userId
WHERE Friends.user1 = :userid
```

Then in the loop:

```
$profiles = array()
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $profiles[] = new Profile($data);
}
```

One perhaps cleaner solution would be to make it a method of the `Profile` class.

```
Profile::getFriendsProfiles()
```

The loop:

```
$profiles = array()
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $profiles[] = new self($data);
}
```

The constructor from `Profile` could be:

```
function __constructor(array $data = null)
{
    if (null !== $data) {
        // fill properties
        $this->id_profile = $data['id_profile']; // example
        ...
    }
}
```

It would be better if the SQL code would be in another object the `Table Data Gateway`.
If you really wan't to improve your OOP then read about software design patterns.
You can start with Martin Fowlers's site [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).